# React Side bar - to navigate similar to link provided

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React JS and would like few ideas regarding implementing the side navigation.

We have Side Nav currently which gets generated from an API response in below structure.
A section may or may not have a subsection. Also, Subsection may or may not have a sub of sub-section. This can be infinite.

```
abc-SECTION
      abcdef-SUB-SECTION
           woirlew-SUB-SUB-SECTION
   ABCDWER-SUB-SECTION
   ABCDXDC
        WERLLWWR-SUB-SUB-SECTION
xyz-SECTION
   XYZSERF-SUB-SECTION
   XYZlJIO-SUB-SECTION
owe-SECTION
      abcdef-SUB-SECTION
      ABCDWER-SUB-SECTION
                slfjl-SUB-SECTION
```

We want to keep the tree structure as above but want to our tree structure to behave something similar to below link.

https://www.hindustantimes.com/interactives/aap-government-two-years-report-card/

We already have a side bar rendering implemented using recursive function. I am looking for scrolling behaviour.

Any guidance would be appreciated. What would be the good way to start with?

Answer (score 0):

To create sidebar can create kind of recursive Component in reactjs.

```
class Tree extends Component {
  render() {
    return {
      <div>
        {this.props.children.map((child) => (
          <div key={child.key}>
            <span>{child.name}</span>
            {child.children && <Tree children={child.children} />}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React to render a list you can have a separate function that takes a data structure as an input such as array or object and recursively calls itself to generate a UL, LI structure. Check this [link](http://oskarhane.com/create-a-nested-array-recursively-in-javascript/) out for recursively iterateing through an nested array of objects

For the scrolling behaviour you can usive javascript onClick event handler and window.scrollTop to calculate and scroll smoothly to that place alternatively theres a light-weight library for that behaviour [Click here to Check it out](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll)

Comment: we already have a side bar rendering implemented using recursive function. I was looking for scrolling behaviour.

Comment: @Vicky as you can see i have provided a link for the same